# How can I add eventlisteners to content that has been updated from localstorage?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, local-storage

I am working on a web application that allows for divs to be drag and dropped/rearranged. The new order of the divs is stored in local storage and if the page is refreshed or navigated away from and then back to, the user's chosen order is then fetched from local storage and displayed to the page. So far I have most of these things working, however when the page is refreshed/navigated away from and back to, the divs are no longer able to be moved around. In the console it appears that the event listeners are no longer on the draggable targets. How can I structure/edit my code so that the divs can be rearranged even if the user has refreshed or come back to the page at a later point in time? (I think the way I am handling events currently is also not very good, so suggestions for how to improve that are more than welcome.)

```
// get two groups of elements, those that are draggable and those that are drop targets
var draggable = document.querySelectorAll('[draggable]');
var targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-drop-target]');

// div immediately surrounding bus routes
var busList = document.getElementById("bus-list");

var busListBuses = busList.children;
// make array from busListBuses which is an htmlCollection (not currently using this)
var divArr = Array.from(busListBuses);

// store the id of the draggable element when drag starts
function handleDragStart(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text", this.id); // sets 'text' value to equal the id of this
  this.classList.add("drag-start"); // class for styling the element being dragged 
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
  e.target.classList.remove('drag-start');
}

function handleDragEnterLeave(e) {
  //
}

// handles dragover event (moving your source div over the target div element)
// If drop event occurs, the function retrieves the draggable element’s id from the DataTransfer object
function handleOverDrop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var draggedId = e.dataTransfer.getData("text"); // retrieves drag data (DOMString) for specified type
  var draggedEl = document.getElementById(draggedId);

  draggedEl.parentNode.insertBefore(draggedEl, this); // inserts element being dragged into list

  var draggedArray = Array.from(draggedEl.parentNode.children); // creates new array which updates current location of each route

  if (e.type === "drop") {
    // when dropped, update localstorage
    savePage(draggedArray);
  }
}

// get each full bus-route div in #bus-list with p content as single arr item each

// called when item is dropped
function savePage(dArray) {
  // honestly i can't remember what this does precisely
  // but i can't seem to add to localstorage in the way i want without it
  var arr = Array.prototype.map.call(dArray, function(elem) {
    return elem.outerHTML;
  });
  localStorage.newList = JSON.stringify(arr); // have to stringify the array in order to add it to localstorage
}


// ideally it should just update the order of the bus routes to reflect local storage
// and add classes/ids to the divs etc. (hence using outerHTML)
function restorePage() {
  // getting the item from localstorage
  var getData = localStorage.getItem("newList");

  // parsing it back into an array
  var parsedData = JSON.parse(getData);

  // string to hold contents of array so they can be display via innerHTML
  var fullList = "";
  if (localStorage.getItem("newList") === null) {
    return; // maybe this is wrong but if there's nothing in local storage, don't do anything
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < parsedData.length; i++) {
      fullList = fullList + parsedData[i];
    }
    busList.innerHTML = fullList;
  }
}

// submit button to save changes to db


// probably better way to do this
for (let i = 0; i < draggable.length; i++) {
  draggable[i].addEventListener("dragstart", handleDragStart);
  draggable[i].addEventListener("dragend", handleDragEnd);
}

// drop target elements
for (let i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
  targets[i].addEventListener("dragover", handleOverDrop);
  targets[i].addEventListener("drop", handleOverDrop);
  targets[i].addEventListener("dragenter", handleDragEnterLeave);
  targets[i].addEventListener("dragleave", handleDragEnterLeave);
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  restorePage();
});
```

I am using React with Pug, here is the Pug file in case that's helpful.

```
html
  head
    title
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='stylesheets/normalize.css' )
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='stylesheets/style.css' )
  body
    div.container
      div#bus-list
        for route in routeInfo
          - var routeID = route.ID
          - var routePos = route.position
          div(class=route.type, draggable="true", data-drop-target="true", id=`r-${routePos}`).bus-route 
            p #{route.route} #{route.route_name}
      button(type="submit", value="submit") done!
  script(src='js/styling.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in the sequence of your code.
JavaScript code is bening parsed as script. So browser executes commands during script loading.

How it works:

1. Browser loads DOM without any items
2. Browser loads JS and adds listeners to the elements (which aren't loaded yet)
3. Brower fires `onLoad()` and your script loads elements from the storage.
4. End of the cycle.

You need to add listeners after you load the elements. Not before that.

#### Off topic

You do some repetitive calls.

You do

```
var getData = localStorage.getItem("newList");
var parsedData = JSON.parse(getData);
var fullList = "";
if (localStorage.getItem("newList") === null) {
  return;
}
```

Instead of

```
var getData = localStorage.getItem("newList");
if (getData === null) {
  return;
}
var parsedData = JSON.parse(getData);
var fullList = "";
```

It hurts readability and perfomance.

I would suggest you to read some books about C languague and Code Style. That will help you on your journey.